# file-based (or package-based) RouterFunction in a spring boot webflux app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

One of the things we want in an internal company framework is file path or package based routes in a spring boot app.
Luckily, in java, file and packages are the same...so either works.

for example, i want to enforce that all packages under `org.company.api` will be picked up from their package name.
so a controller in `org.company.api.user` will be `/user` and `org.company.api.user.login` will be `/user/login`.
NOTE: remember `org.company` can vary from project to project. basically we want  everything under the directory api (which is equivalent to the api subpackage) to be used for this.

I think i can achieve this using webflux router functions, but im not sure if there is a better way. How would the routerfunctions be generated for all files under a directory ?

Comment: what you want to do actually ? Then how do you define if a method is POST or GET or should matched to a particular content-type etc ?  Also , if the method is just a normal java method which you can use any input and output type ? because if you want to use RouterFunction , the java method must be in the ServerRequest and ServerResponse type.

Comment: Also, not really sure what do you want to achieve. Please explain problem more clearly and provide some simple code  example if possible

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to automatically add a path prefix to every controller method 's URL and the path prefix should be derived from the controller 's package name.

You can do it by `RouterFunction` but it requires to implement the controller method (i.e. `HandlerFunction`) using `ServerRequest` as the input parameter and `ServerResponse` as the output. So if you want to implement the controller method as a normal java method which can use any types as the input and output, you need to implement some codes to convert between the `ServerRequest`/ `ServerResponse` to any input and output type in order to adapt `HandlerFunction` can invoke any normal java method etc. You will then end up notice that you are re-inventing things that are already done by the spring-mvc annotated controller approach.

Actually spring-mvc already allows to customise a path prefix of a controller method using `PathMatchConfigurer` (see [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-config-path-matching) at here). But using `PathMatchConfigurer` is quite static which require you to manually maintain all the path prefixes. So in order to be more dynamic to configure all path prefixes based on the controller 's package automatically , we need another way to do it.

Under the cover what `PathMatchConfigurer` does is just configure the [`pathPrefixes`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html#setPathPrefixes-java.util.Map-) inside `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` before it is instantiated. So we need a way to configure it before it instantiates `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` but after we have enough information to know all path prefixes we need to configure which happen after we know which controller beans will be created by spring.

`BeanFactoryPostProcessor` exactly provides such hook which allow to execute codes before instantiating any beans but after all the bean metadata (i.e. `BeanDefinition`) are collected. So we can implement a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` which its job is to configure this `pathPrefixes` map for `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` bean by finding out all packages that containing controller and then configure a path prefix for each of those package.

The following `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` should be a good staring point for you.

```java
    public class PathPrefixFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

        private final String rootPackage;

        public FooBeanFactoryPostProcessor(String rootPackage) {
            this.rootPackage = rootPackage;
        }

        @Override
        public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {

            List<String> controllerPackageNames = findPackageContainController(beanFactory);

            Map<String, Predicate<Class<?>>> pathPrefixesMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (String packageName : controllerPackageNames) {
                if (packageName.startsWith(rootPackage)) {
                    String pathPrefix = packageName.substring(rootPackage.length());
                    pathPrefix = pathPrefix.replace(".", "/");
                    pathPrefixesMap.put(pathPrefix, HandlerTypePredicate.forBasePackage(packageName));
                }

            }
            if(!pathPrefixesMap.isEmpty()){
               BeanDefinition def = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition("requestMappingHandlerMapping");
               def.getPropertyValues().add("pathPrefixes", pathPrefixesMap);
            }
        }

        private List<String> findPackageContainController(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String bdName : beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
                BeanDefinition bd = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(bdName);

                Class<?> type = bd.getResolvableType().resolve();
                if (type != null) {
                    if (AnnotatedElementUtils.hasAnnotation(type, Controller.class) ||
                            AnnotatedElementUtils.hasAnnotation(type, RequestMapping.class)) {
                        result.add(type.getPackageName());
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

- It is assumed that you configure the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` bean has the name `requestMappingHandlerMapping` (which should be by default)
- If the package that containing a controller class does not start with `org.company.api` , no path prefix will be added.

And then define it as a bean :

```
@Configuraiton
public class Config {
    
    @Bean
    public PathPrefixFactoryPostProcessor pathPrefixFactoryPostProcessor(){
        return new PathPrefixFactoryPostProcessor("org.company.api");
    }
}
```

Then given both `org.company.api.user` and `org.company.api.user.login` package contains the following controller

```
@RestController
public class FooController {
    
   @GetMapping("/foo")
   public String foo(){

   }
}
```

The `foo()` is mapped to

- `/user/foo` for the package `org.company.api.user`
- `/user/login/foo` for the package `org.company.api.user.login`

Comment: thanks for the reply. I attempted this . Do you think this works better ? https://github.com/lezter-prog/automaticRouterFunction/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/portfolio/api/RouterAPI.java

Comment: good try but i would not use these codes in production. Also do not know what is your intention to open a `File` . If you want to access a java class 's metadata , reflection API already can do that. Also , if you package you application as JAR , it won't work as all the java file will be complied to .class. there are no `.java` file , and also do not have the  `/src/main/java` folder etc.

Comment: so my advice is forget the RouterFunction and stick to my spring-mvc annotation approach , and if you find my answer is useful , consider to accept it and upvote it as i spend a lot of effort to help you for free.thanks